# VBA to Decipher between a regular SELECT query vs any type of ACTION query in MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can I decipher a simple SELECT query vs an Action Query?

I have a loop that edits a query if the name matches a name in my table.  The code works, but I want it to skip over any action query i.e. UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, etc.

I thought I could simply check `LEFT(qdf.sql,6)` for "SELECT"  but any action query that involves selecting another query will begin with 'SELECT'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually each type of query has its own integer value. By this integer value you can define the type of query. Here is few sample. You will get these integer value by below line

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourQuery").Type
```

---

```
 0   SELECT Query
 128 UNION Query
 32  DELETE Query
 48  UPDATE Query
 64  APPEND Query
```

If you want to return action `First Word` of a query then extract first word from query SQL statement. Loop through all query and get first word. try below sub.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim qSQL As String
Dim qAction As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        qSQL = qdf.SQL  'CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query7").SQL
        qAction = Left(qSQL, InStr(1, qSQL, " ") - 1)
        Debug.Print qAction
        Debug.Print "Type Integer Value= " & qdf.Type
    Next

End Sub
```

***Please note:*** This sub will not work if parameter is defined at starting of query. Then you have to use `QueryDef.Type` property to determine query type.

> ***Edit:*** Use `Select Case` statement to define each query type. See below. You have explore more for other queries.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        Select Case qdf.Type
            Case dbQSelect
                Debug.Print qdf.Name; " is a SELECT Query."
            Case dbQDelete
                Debug.Print qdf.Name; " is a DELETE Query."
            Case dbQUpdate
                Debug.Print qdf.Name; " is a UPDATE Query."
            Case dbQAppend
                Debug.Print qdf.Name; " is a APPEND Query."
            Case dbQSetOperation
                Debug.Print qdf.Name; " is a UNION Query."
            Case Else
                Debug.Print "Something else."
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use numerals. Use the constants like `dbQSelect` as listed in the docs.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for pointing best practice. I have updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the *Type* property of each QueryDef object and skip those you don't want to handle:

[QueryDef.Type property (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-type-property-dao?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)